# How to return the instance of first-class module's nested type from a function?

Tags: generics, ocaml, observer-pattern, first-class-modules

#### Context:

I am trying to implement something like OOP observable pattern in OCaml with using first-class modules. I have a project with a list of modules and want to extend them with observation without changing. To minimize code duplication I created **Subject** module and plan to use it as a part of the common way (in the project context) for this extending. I declared three module types:

**OBSERVER:**

```ml
module type OBSERVER = sig
  type event
  type t

  val send : event -> t -> t
end
```

**OBSERVABLE:**

```ml
module type OBSERVABLE = sig
  type event
  type subscr
  type t

  module type OBSERVER = OBSERVER with type event = event

  val subscribe   : (module OBSERVER with type t = 't) -> 't -> t -> (subscr * t)
  val unsubscribe : subscr -> t -> t
end
```

and **SUBJECT** that is merging of **OBSERVER** and **OBSERVABLE**:

```ml
module type SUBJECT = sig
  include OBSERVER
  include OBSERVABLE 
     with type event := event
      and type t := t
end
```

The next thing that I implemented is **Subject** module. 
The responsibility of this module is to aggregate many **OBSERVER**s into one.
Of course, they should process the same **event** type and that's why I implemented "**Subject**" (**Subject.Make**) as a functor.

```ml
module Subject = struct
  module Make (Event : sig type t end) : sig
    include SUBJECT with type event = Event.t 
    val empty : t
  end = struct
    type event = Event.t
    module type OBSERVER = OBSERVER with type event = event
...
```

To store instances of **OBSERVER**'s first-class modules with the ability to add and remove (in any order) them I use **Map** with **int** as **key** (which is **subscr**).

```ml
...
    type subscr = int 
    module SMap = Map.Make (Int)
...
```

As we can see from **send** signature in **OBSERVER** (`val send : event -> t -> t`) it isn't only necessary to store instances of **OBSERVER**'s first-class modules but also *states* of them (instances of "**OBSERVER.t**"). I can't store all *states* in one collection because of different types. So I declared module type **PACK** to pack instance of **OBSERVER**'s first-class module and instance of its state together in the instance of **PACK**.

```ml
...
    module type PACK = sig
      module Observer : OBSERVER
      val state : Observer.t    
    end

    type t =
      { next_subscr : subscr;
          observers : (module PACK) SMap.t
      }

    let empty =
      { next_subscr = 0;
        observers = SMap.empty
      }

    let subscribe (type t)
        (module Obs : OBSERVER with type t = t) init o =
      o.next_subscr,
      { next_subscr = succ o.next_subscr;
        observers = o.observers |> SMap.add 
                      o.next_subscr
                      ( module struct
                          module Observer = Obs
                          let state = init
                        end : PACK
                      ) 
      }

    let unsubscribe subscription o =
      { o with
        observers = o.observers |> SMap.remove subscription 
      }
...
```

Function **send** of **Subject** repacks each *pack* within new *state* and within old **Observer** module.

```ml
...
    let send event o =
      let send (module Pack : PACK) = 
        ( module struct
            module Observer = Pack.Observer
            let state = Observer.send event Pack.state
          end : PACK
        ) in
      { o with
        observers = SMap.map send o.observers
      }
  end
end
```

To test **Subject** and to see how module extending with observation without changes will look - I created some module **Acc**

```ml
module Acc : sig 
  type t
  val zero : t
  val add : int -> t -> t
  val multiply : int -> t -> t
  val value : t -> int
end = struct
  type t = int
  let zero = 0
  let add x o = o + x
  let multiply x o = o * x
  let value o = o
end
```

And extended it with observation functionality in module **OAcc** with the following signature that is merging of **OBSERVABLE** and module type of original **Acc**

```ml
module OAcc : sig 
  type event = Add of int | Multiply of int

  include module type of Acc
  include OBSERVABLE with type event := event
                      and type t := t 
end = 
...
```

I implemented **OAcc** with the delegation of observation responsibility to **Subject** and main responsibility to original **Acc**.

```ml
...
struct
  type event = Add of int | Multiply of int      
  module Subject = Subject.Make (struct type t = event end)
  module type OBSERVER = Subject.OBSERVER                         
  type subscr = Subject.subscr
  type t = 
    { subject : Subject.t;
      acc : Acc.t
    }

  let zero = 
    { subject = Subject.empty;
      acc = Acc.zero
    } 
  let add x o = 
    { subject = Subject.send (Add x) o.subject;
      acc = Acc.add x o.acc
    } 
  let multiply x o = 
    { subject = Subject.send (Multiply x) o.subject;
      acc = Acc.multiply x o.acc
    }

  let value o = Acc.value o.acc

  let subscribe (type t) (module Obs : Subject.OBSERVER with type t = t) init o =
    let subscription, subject = 
      Subject.subscribe (module Obs) init o.subject in
    subscription, { o with subject }

  let unsubscribe subscription o =
    { o with subject = Subject.unsubscribe subscription o.subject
    } 
end
```

Created some "**OBSERVER** module" that just prints operations into the console

```ml
module Printer : sig 
  include OAcc.OBSERVER
  val make : string -> t
end = struct
  type event = OAcc.event
  type t = string
  let make prefix = prefix
  let send event o = 
    let () = 
      [ o;
        ( match event with
          | OAcc.Add      x -> "Add("      ^ (string_of_int x) 
          | OAcc.Multiply x -> "Multiply(" ^ (string_of_int x)
        );
        ");\n"
      ] 
      |> String.concat ""
      |> print_string in
    o
end
```

Finally, I created function **print_operations** and tested that all works as expected

```ml
let print_operations () =
  let p = (module Printer : OAcc.OBSERVER with type t = Printer.t) in 
  let acc = OAcc.zero in
  let s1, acc = acc |> OAcc.subscribe p (Printer.make "1.") in 
  let s2, acc = acc |> OAcc.subscribe p (Printer.make "2.") in 
  let s3, acc = acc |> OAcc.subscribe p (Printer.make "3.") in
  acc |> OAcc.add 1
      |> OAcc.multiply 2
      |> OAcc.unsubscribe s2 
      |> OAcc.multiply 3
      |> OAcc.add 4 
      |> OAcc.unsubscribe s3
      |> OAcc.add 5
      |> OAcc.unsubscribe s1
      |> OAcc.multiply 6
      |> OAcc.value
```

After calling `print_operations ();;` I have the following output

> # print_operations ();;
>
> > 1.Add(1);
> >     2.Add(1);
> >     3.Add(1);
> >     1.Multiply(2);
> >     2.Multiply(2);
> >     3.Multiply(2);
> >     1.Multiply(3);
> >     3.Multiply(3);
> >     1.Add(4);
> >     3.Add(4);
> >     1.Add(5);
>
> - : int = 90

All works fine in the case when the logic of our first-class module *observer* is totally based on side effects and we don't need state of it outside **Subject**. But for the opposite situation, I didn't found any solution on how to extract the *state* of subscribed *observer* from **Subject**.

For example, I have the following "**OBSERVER**" 
(In this case it more visitor then observer)

```ml
module History : sig 
  include OAcc.OBSERVER
  val empty : t
  val to_list : t -> event list
end = struct
  type event = OAcc.event
  type t = event list
  let empty = []
  let send event o = event :: o
  let to_list = List.rev
end
```

I can subscribe the first-class instance of **History** and some initial state of it to **OAcc** but I don't know how to extract it back.

```ml
let history_of_operations () = 
  let h = (module History : OAcc.OBSERVER with type t = History.t) in 
  let acc = OAcc.zero in
  let s, acc = acc |> OAcc.subscribe h History.empty in
  let history : History.t = 
    acc |> OAcc.add 1
        |> OAcc.multiply 2 
        |> failwith "implement extraction of History.t from OAcc.t" in
  history
```

---

What I tried to do. I changed the signature of *unsubscribe* in **OBSERVABLE**. Before it returns the state of "**OBSERVABLE**" without "**OBSERVER**" associated with the provided subscription and now it returns triple of this state, unsubscribed first-class module, and state of the unsubscribed module.

before:

```ml
module type OBSERVABLE = sig
  ...
  val unsubscribe : subscr -> t -> t
end
```

after:

```ml
module type OBSERVABLE = sig
  ...
  val unsubscribe : subscr -> t -> (t * (module OBSERVER with type t = 't) * 't))
end
```

**OBSERVABLE** is compilable but I can't implement it. 
The following example shows one of my tries.

```ml
module Subject = struct
  module Make (Event : sig type t end) : sig
...
  end = struct
...
    let unsubscribe subscription o =
      let (module Pack : PACK) =
        o.observers |> SMap.find subscription
      and observers = 
        o.observers |> SMap.remove subscription in 
      { o with observers },
      (module Pack.Observer : OBSERVER),
      Pack.state
...
  end
end
```

As a result, I have:

> ```
>     Pack.state 
>     ^^^^^^^^^^
> ```
>
> Error: This expression has type Pack.Observer.t
>   but an expression was expected of type 'a
>   The type constructor Pack.Observer.t would escape its scope

#### Question 1:

Is it possible to implement **unsubscribe** with this signature?

---

It doesn't work. I tried another solution. 
It based on the idea that **unsubscribe** can return an instance of **PACK**'s first-class module.
I like the previous idea better because it keeps the declaration of **PACK** as private in **Subject**. But the current one provides better progress in solution-finding.

I added **PACK** module type into **OBSERVABLE** and changed **unsubscribe** signature to the following.

```ml
module type OBSERVABLE = sig
...
  module type PACK = sig
    module Observer : OBSERVER
    val state : Observer.t    
  end
...
  val unsubscribe : subscr -> t -> (t * (module PACK))
end
```

Added **PACK** into **OAcc** implementation because its signature includes **OBSERVABLE**. Also, I reimplemented **unsubscribe** of **OAcc**.

```ml
module OAcc : sig 
...
end = struct
...
  module type PACK = Subject.PACK
...       
  let unsubscribe subscription o =
    let subject, ((module Pack : PACK) as p) = 
      Subject.unsubscribe subscription o.subject in
    { o with subject }, p 
end
```

Implementation of **Subject** already contains **PACK**, so no need to add it. 
Only **unsubscribe** was reimplemented.

```ml
module Subject = struct
  module Make (Event : sig type t end) : sig
...
  end = struct
...
    let unsubscribe subscription o = 
      let ((module Pack : PACK) as p) =
        o.observers |> SMap.find subscription
      and observers = 
        o.observers |> SMap.remove subscription in 
      { o with observers }, p
...
  end
end
```

Finally, I created I changed **history_of_operations** to test solution

```ml
let history_of_operations () = 
  let h = (module History : OAcc.OBSERVER with type t = History.t) in 
  let acc = OAcc.zero in
  let s, acc = acc |> OAcc.subscribe h History.empty in
  let acc, (module Pack : OAcc.PACK) = 
    acc
    |> OAcc.add 1
    |> OAcc.multiply 2 
    |> OAcc.unsubscribe s in
  Pack.state ;;
```

After calling `history_of_operations ();;` I have the error

> ```ml
>   Pack.state
>   ^^^^^^^^^^
> ```
>
> Error: This expression has type Pack.Observer.t
>   but an expression was expected of type 'a
>   The type constructor Pack.Observer.t would escape its scope

Also, I tried

```ml
let history_of_operations () = 
...
    History.to_list Pack.state
```

But

> ```ml
>   History.to_list Pack.state
>                   ^^^^^^^^^^
> ```
>
> Error: This expression has type Pack.Observer.t
>   but an expression was expected of type History.t

#### Question 2:

How to extract the state from **Pack** with type **List.t**?

---

I changed the signature of **unsubscribe**

```ml
module type OBSERVABLE = sig
...
  val unsubscribe : subscr -> t -> (t * (module PACK with type Observer.t = 't))
end
```

And tried to reimplement **unsubscribe** in **Subject**

```ml
module Subject = struct
  module Make (Event : sig type t end) : sig
...
  end = struct
...
    let unsubscribe (type t) subscription o = 
      let ((module Pack : PACK with type Observer.t = t) as p) =
        o.observers |> SMap.find subscription
      and observers = 
        o.observers |> SMap.remove subscription in 
      { o with observers }, p
...
  end
end
```

But

> ```ml
>       o.observers |> SMap.find subscription
>       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> ```
>
> Error: This expression has type (module PACK)
>   but an expression was expected of type
>   (module PACK with type Observer.t = t)

It looks like OCaml has 3 *levels of types abstraction*
1. Concrete `module A : sig type t = int end = struct ...`
2. Abstract `module A : sig type t end = struct ...`
3. Packed to first-class module

#### Question 3:

Is it possible to store nested type of instance of the first-class module with **(2)** *level of abstraction* or with the ability to restore it to **(2)** *level of abstraction*?

---

#### The question from the title:

How to return the instance of first-class module's nested type from a function?

---

#### Remark:

Of course, it is possible to solve this problem by mutable state using but the question isn't about.

The initial compilable source code [here](https://gist.github.com/vzakh/79a3f95c1bd487efa6ea77c2faab36fd).

Comment: solution: gist.github.com/vzakh/017cc4314404dc089fa5a3116148c052

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disclaimer: I won't pretend that I fully understand your question, this is by far the largest OCaml-related question I have seen on SO. But my intuition tells me that you're looking for existentials.

## Simple existentials with no type equality

In this approach we can pack an object interface together with its state in a single existential GADT. We will be able to use the state as long as it doesn't escape the scope of its definition, which will be the function that unpacks our existential. Sometimes, it is what we want, but we will extend this approach in the next section.

Let's start with some preliminary definitions, let's define the interface of the object that we would like to pack, e.g., something like this:

```
module type T = sig
  type t
  val int : int -> t
  val add : t -> t -> t
  val sub : t -> t -> t
  val out : t -> unit
end
```

Now, we can pack this interface together with the state (a value of type `t`) in an existential

```
type obj = Object : {
    intf : (module T with type t = 'a);
    self : 'a
  } -> obj
```

We can then easily unpack the interface and the state and apply any function from the interface to the state. Therefore, our type `t` is purely abstract, and indeed [existential types are abstract types](http://theory.stanford.edu/people/jcm/papers/mitch-plotkin-88.pdf), e.g.,

```
module Int = struct
  type t = int
  let int x = x
  let add = (+)
  let sub = (-)
  let out = print_int
end

let zero = Object {
    intf = (module Int);
    self = 0;
  }

let incr (Object {intf=(module T); self}) = Object {
    intf = (module T);
    self = T.add self (T.int 1)
  }

let out (Object {intf=(module T); self}) = T.out self
```

## Recoverable Existentials (aka Dynamic types)

But what if would like to recover the original type of the abstract type so that we can apply other functions that are applicable to values of this type. For that we need to store a witness that the type `x` belongs to the desired type `y`, which we can do, employing extensible GADT,

```
 type 'a witness = ..
```

To create new witnesses, we will employ first-class modules,

```
let newtype (type u) () =
  let module Witness = struct
    type t = u
    type _ witness += Id : t witness
  end in
  (module Witness : Witness with type t = u)
```

where module type `Witness` and its packed types are,

```
module type Witness = sig 
     type t 
     type _ witness += Id : t witness
end

type 'a typeid = (module Witness with type t = 'a)
```

Every time `newtype` is called it adds a new constructor to the witness type that is guaranteed not to be equal to any other constructor. To prove that two witness are actually created with the same constructor we will use the following function,

```
let try_cast : type a b. a typeid -> b typeid -> (a,b) eq option =
  fun x y ->
  let module X : Witness with type t = a = (val x) in
  let module Y : Witness with type t = b = (val y) in
  match X.Id with
  | Y.Id -> Some Equal
  | _ -> None
```

which returns the equality proof that is defined as,

```
type ('a,'b) eq = Equal : ('a,'a) eq
```

In the environments in which we can construct an object of type `(x,y) eq` the typechecker will treat values of type `x` having the same type as `y`. Sometimes, when you are really sure that the cast must success, you can use, the `cast` function,

```
let cast x y = match try_cast x y with
  | None -> failwith "Type error"
  | Some Equal -> Equal
```

as,

```
let Equal = cast t1 t2 in
(* here we have proved that types witnessed by t1 and t2 are the same *)
```

Ok, now when we have the dynamic types, we can employ them to make our object types recoverable and state escapable. What we need, is just to add runtime information to our object representation,

```
type obj = Object : {
    intf : (module T with type t = 'a);
    self : 'a;
    rtti : 'a typeid;
  } -> obj
```

Now let's define the runtime representation for type `int` (note that in general we can put more information in rtti, other just the witness, we can also make it an oredered type and extend dynamic types in runtime with new operations, and implement ad hoc polymorphism),

```
let int : int typeid = newtype ()
```

So now our `zero` object is defined as,

```
let zero = Object {
    intf = (module Int);
    self = 0;
    rtti = int;
  }
```

The `incr` function is still the same (modulo an extra field in the object representation), since it doesn't require escaping. But now we can write the `cast_object` function that will take the desired type and cast object to it,

```
let cast_object (type a) (t : a typeid) (Object {self; rtti}) : a option =
  match try_cast t rtti with
  | Some Equal -> Some self
  | None -> None
```

and

```
# cast_object int zero;;
- : int option = Some 0
# cast_object int (incr zero);;
- : int option = Some 1
```

Another example,

```
let print_if_int (Object {self; rtti}) =
  match try_cast int rtti with
  | Some Equal -> print_int self
  | None -> ()
```

You can read more about dynamic types [here](https://discuss.ocaml.org/t/types-as-first-class-citizens-in-ocaml/2030/3). There are also many libraries in OCaml that provide dynamic types and heterogeneous dictionaries, and so on.

Comment: It wasn't easy but I think I understood existentials and "Dynamic" types. Source code of solution for my example is here: https://gist.github.com/vzakh/017cc4314404dc089fa5a3116148c052

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your question 1, you expect a function with signature:

```
val unsubscribe : subscr -> t -> (t * (module OBSERVER with type t = 't) * 't))
```

The presence of a module is a red herring here. Your signature is no different from

```
val unsubscribe : subscr -> t -> 'a
```

In other words, it is a function that magically returns a value of any type that the caller might desire. If the caller wants an integer, the function returns an integer. If the caller wants a string, the function returns a string. And so on. Thus, there is only one kind of safe function with this kind of signature, it is a function that never returns anything.

So, you need to move the quantification over types elsewhere, for example under a constructor:

```ml
type 'u unsubscribe_result = UResult: 'u *  (module OBSERVER with type t = 't) * 't -> 'u unsubscribe_result
val unsubscribe : subscr -> t -> t unsubscribe_result
```

Comment: Note that your unsubscribe result type is equivalent to simply returning a pair (t * (module PACK)) and that the type of observer state is still unknown.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that the inner types of packed modules can never be lifted outside of their first-class modules.

When you define a packed observer as:

```ml
  module type PACK = sig
    module Observer: sig
      type t
      val send: event -> t -> t
    end
    val state: Observer.t
  end
```

the type `Observer.t` is existentially quantified within the first-class module: by packing the initial implementation inside a `(module PACK)`, I am forgetting all that I know about the initial module, except for the type equalities inside the modules. 
This means that for a value `(module M)` of type `(module PACK)`, the only action that is available to me is to call `M.Observer.send event M.state`.
In other words, `(module PACK)` is in fact equivalent to the following type

```ml
type send = { send: event -> send }
```

where the state of `Observer` is more visibly inaccessible.

Thus, your problem started when you packed your observers in

```ml
    let subscribe (type t)
        (module Obs : OBSERVER with type t = t) init o =
      o.next_subscr,
      { next_subscr = succ o.next_subscr;
        observers = o.observers |> SMap.add 
                      o.next_subscr
                      ( module struct
                          module Observer = Obs
                          let state = init
                        end : PACK
                      ) 
      }
```

Here, when you pack the module `Obs`, you are in fact forgetting the type of `Obs` and forgoing any further use of this type.

If you want to get back the state of the observer, you must keep the type information. A good starting point is to look at the OBSERVABLE signature:

```ml
module type OBSERVABLE = sig
  type event
  type subscr
  type t

  module type OBSERVER = OBSERVER with type event = event
  val subscribe : (module OBSERVER  with type t = 't) -> 't -> t -> (subscr * t)
  val unsubscribe : subscr -> t -> t
end
```

and notice that we start losing type information in `subscribe` because I cannot associate a specific `subscr` with an observable type. One solution is thus to keep this information by parameterizing `subscr` with the type of the subscribed observer:

```
module type OBSERVABLE = sig
  type event
  type 'a subscr
  type t

  module type OBSERVER = OBSERVER with type event = event
  val subscribe : (module OBSERVER  with type t = 't) -> 't -> t -> ('t subscr * t)
  val unsubscribe : 't subscr -> t -> t
end
```

Then, with this change, `unsubscribe` can return the current state of the observer, because we know the type of this state: it is the type stored by the subscription:

```ml
  val unsubscribe : 't subscr -> t -> t * 't
```

The remaining issue is thus storing observers in a map whose type depends on the type of the key that inserted them. This constraint points to a heterogeneous map. Using the [hmap](https://erratique.ch/software/hmap/doc/Hmap.S.Key) library, this can be done with:

```ml
module Subject = struct
  module Make (Event : sig type t end) : sig
    include SUBJECT with type event = Event.t
    val empty : t
  end = struct
    type event = Event.t
    module type OBSERVER =
      OBSERVER with type event = event
    (* we need to keep the module implementation with the key for map *)
    module HM = Hmap.Make(struct type 'a t = (module OBSERVER  with type t = 'a) end)
    type t = HM.t
    type 'a subscr = 'a HM.key


    let empty = HM.empty

    let subscribe (type t)
        (((module Obs) :  (module OBSERVER  with type t = t) ) as vt) (init:t) o =
      let key: t subscr = HM.Key.create vt in
      key, HM.add key init o

    let unsubscribe subscription o =
      HM.rem subscription o, HM.get subscription o

    let send event o =
      let send_and_readd (HM.B(k,s)) o =
        let module Obs = (val HM.Key.info k) in
        let s = Obs.send event s in
        HM.add k s o in
      HM.fold send_and_readd o empty
  end
end
```

Comment: "heterogeneous map" - is something that I never heard before. As I understand I can install **hmap** as a black box with Opam and use it but for me is interesting how it work. I thought about the implementation of a similar structure and for me, it looked impossible. If you have some helpful links to relevant information could you please share them?

Comment: Under the hood, hmap and other heterogeneous map implementation are using type equality witnesses based on extension constructor as described in @ivg answer.