# How to use type-level functions to create static types, dynamically?

Tags: c++, typescript, scala, haskell, ocaml

In TypeScript, there are **type-level** *functions* that allow creating new types based on given **literal** *types/specifications* (see [Mapped Types](https://www.staging-typescript.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types), [Conditional Types](https://www.staging-typescript.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#conditional-types), etc.).

For instance, here is such a *function*, let say provided by a lib author:

```typescript
type FromSpec<S> = { 
  [K in keyof S]: S[K] extends "foo" ? ExampleType : never 
};
```

Its purpose is, given a specification `S` in the form of a map of string keys and arbitrary literals, it creates a new type in the form of a map with the same set of keys and with values transformed. If a the value is the literal `"foo"` then it becomes the type `ExampleType`, otherwise the value is rejected by transforming it into the bottom type `never`.

Then, an end-user can make use of this function to create new types following the above explanation:

```typescript
type Example = FromSpec<{some_key: "foo", another_key: "bar"}>
//           = {some_key: ExampleType, another_key: never}
```

It's noteworthy that the lib author doesn't know about what exact type a given end-user may want, and thus provides him with a function to create the ones he needs. On the other hand, the end-user can create an infinite set of new types as long as he complies with the function's capabilities.

You can play around this simple example, [here](http://www.staging-typescript.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAogHgQwLZgDYQCrmgXigbygH0iAjAJwQDsATCGgLimHIFdoBfKAem6gEEoAIgAWCAMYBrIcwD2UceQgJg0BFCoQA7lBqskSEM2xRZVALRhW5MLIDOEALAAoF6EhQAYuVlIAypDiADx+AHxQeIQuUFAA2gDSUACWVFCSECCyAGZQfgC6TH4JeVAQcKq0dsJZsrIyAPywiCjoWB5MmgBuEORQLhwA3C5uJvDIaLhePv6BQYR2vhBE6SBMQjV1ADRQ1LLAIj3LGWukCOQyHKEuvDG3dzGRUAtISytMYy2Y2AM7VHsH5COqw0EG6vQ4QA).

---

The question is about how this kind of "dynamism" is expressible in other typed languages (e.g., ReasonML/OCaml, Scala, Haskell). Or how, as an end-user, to create new types, **at compile-time**, by using type-level functions, provided by a lib author (as one would usually do at runtime with value-level functions)?

It's important to note that the question is not about which language is better, etc. It's about finding the most straightforward and **explicit** way to express such capabilities. Here we saw an example in TypeScript, but is there any more **natural** way in any other language?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215492/discussion-on-question-by-fsenart-which-programming-language-supports-user-drive).

Comment: @user Done! Please feel free to ask me for more precision. I'm a layman, and my vocabulary may not be the most domain-specific one.

Comment: @fsenart Which answer would you want me to give a bounty to, the one by Alec, or the one by ivg? It doesn't seem like anyone else is going to answer your question, despite the bounty.

Comment: @user IMHO the answer by Alec is the most explicit and extensible way to express such ideas. Scala 3 promotes type-level programming to the status of first-class citizen in the language and it eases the overall reasoning.

Comment: @fsenart All right, I'll award the bounty to Alec on Monday

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given Scala is one of the tagged languages, here is a solution in Dotty (aka. Scala 3). Take this with a grain of salt, since Dotty is still under development. Tested with Dotty version 0.24.0-RC1, here is [a Scastie that proves this actually compiles](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/Tgp2cFJ8TrykFCzZ5Il2tQ).

Scala doesn't have the same sort of built-in type machinery as TypeScript for manipulating records. Not to fear, we can roll our own!

```scala
import deriving._

// A field is literally just a tuple of field name and value
type Field[K, V] = (K, V)

// This just helps type-inference infer singleton types in the right places
def field[K <: String with Singleton, V <: Singleton](
  label: K,
  value: V
): Field[K, V] = label -> value

// Here is an example of some records
val myRec1 = ()
val myRec2 = field("key1", "foo") *: field("key2", "foo") *: () 
val myRec3 =
  field("key1", 1) *: field("key2", "foo") *: field("key3", "hello world") *: ()
```

Then, `FromSpec` can be implemented using a [match-type](https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/new-types/match-types.html). The `never` type in TypeScript is called `Nothing` in Scala/Dotty.

```scala
// Could be defined to be useful - `trait` is just an easy way to bring a new type in 
trait ExampleType
val exampleValue = new ExampleType {}

type FromSpec[S <: Tuple] <: Tuple = S match {
  case Field[k, "foo"] *: rest => Field[k, ExampleType] *: FromSpec[rest]
  case Field[k, v] *: rest => Field[k, Nothing] *: FromSpec[rest]
  case Unit => Unit
}
```

Finally, let's use `FromSpec`:

```scala
def myRec1Spec: FromSpec[myRec1.type] = ()
def myRec2Spec: FromSpec[myRec2.type] =
  field("key1", exampleValue) *: field("key2", exampleValue) *: () 
def myRec3Spec: FromSpec[myRec3.type] = ??? // no non-diverging implementation
```

Comment: thank you so much for your amazing answer. There is one difference with the questions' code: in TypeScript I was pattern matching on the value of the field, not its name (`S[K]` not `K`). Thus if the value of a certain key is the literal "foo" then generate a type with this key and the type `ExampleType`. I think I see how it is possible to do that based on your answer but it would be awesome if you could edit and take this into account. Thank you.

Comment: Woops yeah! I'm not versed in TypeScript. I'll fix though.

Answer (score 4):

> Is it possible to express the same kind of "dynamism" or something close to it in another typed language (e.g., ReasonML/OCaml, Scala, Haskell).

Yes, dynamic types are fully supported by the OCaml/ReasonML type system and are widely used. You can express quite complex dynamic typing rules, e.g., build your hierarchies, implement ad-hoc polymorphism and so on. The main ingredients of the solution is using extensible GADT, first-class modules, and existentials. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62218812/2625442) as one of the example or this discussion for [the general case of universal values](https://discuss.ocaml.org/t/types-as-first-class-citizens-in-ocaml/2030/3?u=ivg), there are also multiple libraries that provide various dynamic typing capabilities in OCaml. Another example is BAP's [Core Theory](https://github.com/BinaryAnalysisPlatform/bap/blob/fbaf190269a3ef14f3acbfde1b786c33d2222e59/lib/bap_core_theory/bap_core_theory.mli#L390) library that has a very complex type hierarchy for value sorts, which includes precise type specifications for various number representations, including floating-point numbers, memories, etc.

To make the answer complete, this is how you can implement your `fromSpec` in OCaml, first we define type that will be bearing the tag for dynamic typing, underneath the hood this is just an integer, but with associated type which it is *witnessing*,

```
type 'a witness = ..
```

To create a new witness (basically incrementing this id) we will use first class modules and append a new constructor using `+=`

```
module type Witness = sig 
     type t 
     type _ witness += Id : t witness
end

type 'a typeid = (module Witness with type t = 'a)

let newtype (type u) () =
  let module Witness = struct
    type t = u
    type _ witness += Id : t witness
  end in
  (module Witness : Witness with type t = u)
```

The type equality proof (the value that proofs to the compiler that two types are the same since they are both using the constructor with the same identity), is commonly represented as `('a,'b) eq` type,

```
type ('a,'b) eq = Equal : ('a,'a) eq
```

And this is how we implement the cast function,

```
let try_cast : type a b. a typeid -> b typeid -> (a,b) eq option =
  fun x y ->
  let module X : Witness with type t = a = (val x) in
  let module Y : Witness with type t = b = (val y) in
  match X.Id with
  | Y.Id -> Some Equal
  | _ -> None
```

finally, your `fromSpec`,

```
type spec {
   data : 'a;
   rtti : 'a typeid
}

let example_type = newtype ()

let example = {
   data = 42;
   rtti = example_type; (* witnesses that data is `int` *)
}

let fromSpec = try_cast example_type
```

Comment: thank you very much for your extensive answer. It's a neat pattern to access runtime type information. Though, do we agree that in OCaml we cannot have this flexibility at compile time? I didn't precise in my question but when I'm talking about type-level programming, I was talking at compile-time implicitly.

Comment: May I also suggest that `try_cast` is the real `fromSpec`. In fact your `spec` is the type of a "value with its runtime type info" and should be named something like `rt_typed_value`, isn't it? Then instead `let spec = fromSpec example_type` (i.e. make use of `fromSpec` to generate a dynamic specification specialized for `example_type`). Moreover, may I detail your example with a witness type that is not only an `int`. In effect, as it is a weakly polymorphic type that is specialized upon usage, it may be a little bit hard to understand how to have `string` data along with `int` data.

Comment: I took the liberty of adding more examples and details. Please feel free to re-organize as desired. Thank you one more time for your insightful answer.

Comment: I'm a little bit confused. Does the type equality proof gives us static type errors with dynamic types? Damn, it feels magic!

Comment: @fsenart, I think I misread your typescript code. For creating static types, we certainly have type constructors and functors with the later being so powerful (basically the dependent typing) that you can code Girard paradox with them. https://github.com/lpw25/girards-paradox/blob/master/girard.ml Given that, could you please explain on a more abstract and general level, what are you seeking?

Comment: I'm looking for a way, at the type level, to generate new types from on-demand given specifications, at the term level  (and statically checkable at compile time). In the TypeScript example, `FromSpec` is a type-level "function" that generates new types on-demand from given specs. For instance `let v: FromSpec<{somekey: "foo"}>` has an effective static type of `let v: {somekey: ExampleType}`. The Scala example given by @Alec is exactly this and far more explicit than the TypeScript one. I'm a layman and my vocabulary isn't precise, but I hope you see the idea.

Comment: is type `'a list `that generates types `int list`, `float list`, `string list` etc a generator for you? Or, alternatively, `module MakeList(T : sig type t end) = struct type t = T.t list end` so that `MakeList(String).t` is `string list`? Basically, what is unclear the _on-demand_ part.

Comment: Also, I have rolled back your edits, please don't take it wrong, but the answer diverged from its original point, so let's start from the square one and try to find out what the question was :) Concerning the dynamic types and RTTI, you're welcome to post another question if you're interested :)

Comment: I'm having a hard time matching this answer to the question. There seems to be no reference to a literal string type `"foo"` and I don't see a bottom type like `never`?

Comment: @Alec, the role of the literal is played by the GADT constructor, but indeed my answer is more general and I am not trying to precisely implement the OP design. It is usually not a good idea to port patterns between languages one-to-one. Anyways, I am in contact with OP and trying to figure out the A problem that he is trying to address, will update the post soonish.

Answer (score 1):

*Disclaimer: I'm not a C++ programmer, so don't take this answer to be the proper way to do it in C++. It is just one way to do it that is extremely brittle and is probably mostly wrong.*

```
//I've used char pointers below, because it's not possible to directly write string //literals in templates without doing some more complex stuff that isn't relevant here

//field1 and field2 are the names of the fields/keys
const char field2[] = "field2";
const char field1[] = "field1";
//foo and bar are the strings that determine what the
//type of the fields will be
const char foo[] = "foo";
const char bar[] = "bar";

//This represents a key and the determining string (foo/bar)
template <const char * name, const char * det>
struct Named {};

//What the type of the field will be if it maps to "foo"
struct ExampleType {
  std::string msg;
};

//The end of a cons structure
struct End{};

//A cons-like structure, but for types
template <typename T, typename N>
struct Cons {
  typedef T type;
  typedef N Next;
};

//This'll be used to create new types
//While it doesn't return a type, per se, you can access the
//"created" type using "FromSpec<...>::type" (see below)
template <typename T>
struct FromSpec;

//This will handle any Named template where the determining string
//is not "foo", and gives void instead of ExampleType
template <const char * name, const char * det, typename rest>
struct FromSpec<Cons<Named<name, det>, rest>> {
  //Kinda uses recursion to find the type for the rest
  typedef Cons<void, typename FromSpec<rest>::type> type;
};

//This will handle cases when the string is "foo"
//The first type in the cons is ExampleType, along with the name
//of the field
template <const char * name, typename rest>
struct FromSpec<Cons<Named<name, foo>, rest>> {
  typedef Cons<ExampleType, typename FromSpec<rest>::type> type;
};

//This deals with when you're at the end
template <>
struct FromSpec<End> {
  typedef End type;
};
```

Now you can use it like this:

```
typedef Cons<Named<field1, foo>, Cons<Named<field2, bar>, End>> C;

//Notice the "::type"
typedef FromSpec<C>::type T;
```

`T` is equivalent to `Cons<ExampleType, Cons<void, End>>`

You can then access the types inside like so:

```
typedef T::type E; //Equivalent to ExampleType
typedef T::type::Next N; //Equivalent to Cons<void, End>
typedef N::type v; //Equivalent to void
```

Example usage

```
int main() {
  ExampleType et = { "This is way too complicated!" };
  //You can kinda have values of type "void", unfortunately,
  //but they're really just null
  //             v
  N inner = { nullptr, new End() };
  T obj = { &et, &inner };
  Cons<ExampleType, Cons<void, End>> obj2 = obj;
  std::cout << et.msg << std::endl;
}
```

Prints "This is way too complicated!"

[Link to repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/PrimeMisguidedText#main.cpp)

Feel free to edit my answer if it has mistakes or if it could be otherwise improved. I mostly just tried to translate [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62263735/11882002) by [@Alec](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3072788/alec) into C++.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. As you told it, it follows pretty much the same kind of pattern matching than the @alec answer. Note that the `ExampleType` is just an example type and is not necessarily in relationship with the name of the field as in your example. Can you please also provide a simple example of a variable declared with the created type and its accompanying example value to make the explanation complete.

Comment: @fsenart Added example usage. It's very basic, but I doubt you need a more detailed explanation. Hope that helps.