# Is it possible to wrap the members types with another type in Scala 3 similar to typescript mapped types?

Tags: scala, dotty, scala-3

In typescript it looks like this

```js
type Option<T> = {some: T} | 'none'
type Optional<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]: Option<T[P]>
};
type Foo = {x: string, y: number}
type OptionalFoo = Optional<Foo>
const foo: OptionalFoo = {x: 'none', y : {some: 123}}
```

```scala
case class Foo(x: String, y: Int)
```

I would like to have

```scala
type OptionalFoo = Optional[Foo] == case class OptionalFoo(x: Option[String], y: Option[Int])
```

Is it possible to achive something like this in Scala 3?

Comment: As far as I know, not when you have a variable number of fields.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62248481/11882002) is a similar question, but I doubt you'll find anything there. You may just have to write a compiler plugin yourself, or find a workaround, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not care about the names of each field, you could perhaps do this:

```scala
type Foo = (String, Int)
type Optional[T <: Tuple] = Tuple.Map[T, Option]
type OptionalFoo = Optional[Foo]

val optionalFoo: OptionalFoo = (Some("foobar"), None)
optionalFoo match {
  case (x, y) => println(s"x is $x, y is $y")
}
```

[Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/FCCmYWcwQEaCmMI03ncQ5g)

This may have been possible in Scala 2, which supported annotation macros. Perhaps [type class derivation](https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/contextual/derivation.html) may also help you here. [Shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless) also has many useful mechanisms if you do not care about actually creating a completely new case class.

Comment: Thanks. Could It be implemented for `type Foo = (("x", String),("y", Int))`? Is it possible to convert case class to such tuples in Scala 3?

Comment: @ais Convert a case class to a tuple? Shapeless can probably do that. But I thought you wanted to make a case class *from* a tuple. Have I misinterpreted your question?

Comment: I thought maybe such scenario could be possible `case class Foo(x: String, x: Int)` convert to tuple `type Foo = (("x", String),("y", Int))` and tranform tuple with `Optional[Foo] ==  (("x", Option[String]),("y", Option[Int]))` and use such tuple as some sort of case class alternative.

Comment: @ais You can directly turn the tuple version of `Foo` into the tuple of tuples. Give me a minute